# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una solicitud GET?

Tags: python

E intentado esto pero me devuelve: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Alguien me puede decir en qué estoy mal

````
import socket

url = "https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update"

for info in socket.getaddrinfo("www.programiz.com", "https", socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
 family, type, proto, canoname, addr = info

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(addr)

header = "GET /python-programming/methods/dictionary/update HTTP/1.0"

sock.send(header.encode("utf-8"))
x = 1024*7
data = sock.recv(x).decode("utf-8")
print(data)```
````

Answer (score 1):

Estas intentando acceder a la URL usando el protocolo HTTPS, para eso usas un Socket TCP normal... pero para acceder a una URL de internet necesitas usar una conexión SSL/TLS cifrada que proporciona una capa adicional de seguridad, para eso te sugiero usar la biblioteca *'requests'* que es una biblioteca de alto nivel y facil de usar, para instalarla (si usas VSCode) escribe en la terminal:

```
pip install requests
```

Ya puedes hacer tus peticiones sin errores:

```
import requests
url = "https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/dictionary/update"
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)
```